# Is is possible to use OpenVPN client as default network gateway (OpenWRT)?

Tags: firewall, routing, openvpn, ip-routing, openwrt

Usually, when using a VPN, you can route all client traffic(s) through a VPN tunnel with a exit point on the VPN server.
Is there a reverse possibility: to organize an exit point to the WWW on the side of one of the VPN clients?

For example, there is a VPN server `server1` (172.16.0.1) and two VPN clients `client1` (172.16.0.2) and `client2` (172.16.0.3).  Is it possible to configure the `client1` device in such a way that the `ip route add default via 172.16.0.2` can be executed on the `client2` device?

I'm interested in whether it is possible to do this, provided that `client1` runs on OpenWRT (with OpenVPN client).

And if it is possible, then what settings should I pay attention to on the `client1` device?

**Updated:**
In fact, I am interested in organizing access to multiple subnets on the side of some clients (for some clients, this is not needed). I would like to avoid the need to prescribe routes to dozens of subnets to the openvpn configurations. At best, I would like to shift the writing of routes to OSPF, at worst - to configure routes on routers (i.e. in the routing tables of routers, not in the VPN config). For many reasons, it is impossible to install BGP, so I need to work with what is there. The `tap` option is as undesirable as possible.

Comment: It is possible on OpenWRT and OpenVPN. Notice that configuration might be not very simple, on either site. For the sake of clarity, draw a network diagram with all desired IP addresses and add into the question. // Also, what *business environment* do you represent with this question? ServerFault is [inappropriate for home-user questions](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), consider asking mods to move it to SuperUser.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov what business environment do I represent? I didn't quite understand what was meant. If you talking about a physical environment, then there are several offices, each of which has several subnets and routers with OSPF. I cannot draw a diagram of a real network for security reasons (especially - static IPs), and besides, it is not required. Is there a difference between 2 networks in the office or 32 if the task is to shift routing to OSFP? "Not very simple" configuration will be where? In OpenVPN? In iptables? Please elaborate.